# Como pausar um progresso de uma Notificação?

Tags: android, mobile, thread, push-notification

Existe uma ProgressBar na minha notificação que funciona assim:

```
new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int incr;

                        // Do the "lengthy" operation 20 times
                        for (incr = 0; incr <= 100; incr += 5) {
                            // Sets the progress indicator to a max value, the
                            // current completion percentage, and "determinate"
                            // state
                            builder.setProgress(100, incr, false);
                            // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
                            m.notify(id, builder.build());
                            // Sleeps the thread, simulating an operation
                            // that takes time

                            try {
                                // Sleep for 5 seconds
                                Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {


                        }
                    }
```

E os dois botões:

```
builder.addAction(R.drawable.Continuar, "Continuar", ??);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.Pausar,"Pausar",??);
```

Alguém saberia como fazer para que os botões pausassem e resumissem o Thread?

Answer (score 0):

Vou dar uma ideia para você , no objeto que cria thread ,declare uma variavel de instancia  booleana 'pausar' , e na Thread:

```
new Thread(
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int incr;

                    // Do the "lengthy" operation 20 times
                    for (incr = 0; incr <= 100; incr += 5) {
                        // Sets the progress indicator to a max value, the
                        // current completion percentage, and "determinate"
                        // state
                        builder.setProgress(100, incr, false);
                        // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
                        m.notify(id, builder.build());
                        // Sleeps the thread, simulating an operation
                        // that takes time
                        do{
                            try {
                              // Sleep for 5 seconds
                              Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                //Quase improvavel de ocorrer
                            }
                        }while(pausar);
                    }
                }
});
```

E então basta mudar 'pausar' para true ou false, pelos botões, que ele vai ficar no loop até você despausar. Usei DO-WHILE para ele executar o sleep pelo menos uma vez.

Comment: Ah, muito obrigado, mas uma coisa, não entendi muito bem como mudar isso pelos botões da Notificação, por que só consigo fazer eles abrirem novas Classes...